# Silent Notifications issues in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working with silent notifications, and what I understood till now is that it works in conditions.
1- Foreground
2- Background
3- Suspended (If suspended then it will wake up and submit the notification)
The problem is that when I am creating build from xcode 5 then I am getting in suspended mode but when I am doing same thing with xcode 6 then I am getting notification except the last one. It has wasted almost my two days but I am unable to solve it, kindly help me out.
Edit:
Sorry I have tested it out, now silent notifications are also creating problems with xcode 5 build. I am simply want to ask that is it works in suspended mode automatically or we have to right some code to handle it in suspended mode?

Comment: bro, plz make ur question less confusing(explain clearly)

Comment: @sanjeet my problem is suspended mode, I am not getting notifications properly in suspended mode

Comment: i don't know about ios8 but i will work with ios7 without writing extra code.

Comment: Yeah it is working fine on iOS 7 but it creates problems in suspended mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind this issue is that in suspended mode wifi goes turn off. And if you want to keep it on then either use GSM network. And there is no way to keep wifi alive in suspended mode, apple don't provide this access.